# What is the function of Silverlight?

Tags: .net

What is the function of [Silverlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Silverlight)?

Comment: To lock the web into the Microsoft silo.

Comment: What is the function of flash?

Comment: watch this in a few days: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/11/17/silverlight-firestarter-event-on-dec-2nd.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if that is meant to be ironic, but it is a .NET plugin providing rich media support and full vector graphics (with GPU acceleration) for use in the web. A "[Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29)" version ([Moonlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moonlight_%28runtime%29)) is also available for Unix.

It certainly has some similarities to Flash, etc., but it is a different implementation, based more on the .NET stack. Of course it is also now at competition with JavaScript and jQuery which get faster and richer at a pace.

The same technology (but a different core) also powers much of Windows Phone 7 development, and *similar* approaches are used in WPF.

Answer (score 1):

The following articles answers various questions about Silverlight.

- [What is Silverlight?](http://faq.programmerworld.net/programming/silverlight.html)
- Why Silverlight? See "[What is Silverlight?](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/what-is-silverlight/)", "[Why Silverlight Is Important](http://techcrunch.com/2007/05/01/take-time-to-understand-silverlight-its-important/)", and "[5 Reasons Why Silverlight Is My Preferred Web Development Platform](http://davybrion.com/blog/2009/09/5-reasons-why-silverlight-is-my-preferred-web-development-platform/)".
- Why do I use Silverlight? See "[WHAT DO WE USE SILVERLIGHT FOR?????](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/122706.aspx)".